# How to store value to var from another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm comparing my two documents named: user and bloodrequest based on their id, if they match then display the values in the table bloodrequest that has the same id. My problem here is that I'm trying to store the current logged in user to a var like this : `var permit = mainUser.branch_id` then used a `$where` statement using this: `this.chapter_id == permit` but gives me error.

> `MongoError: TypeError: mainUser is undefined :`

Here is my code, My only problem is how to pass `mainUser.branch_id` to `var permit`, I'm just starting to learn

```
router.get('/bloodapprovedrequestmanagement', function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if (err) throw err;
        User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!mainUser) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' });
            } if (mainUser.branch_id === '111') {

                Bloodrequest.find({$where: function(err) {
                        var permit = mainUser.branch_id//gives me error here
                        return (this.request_status == "approved" && this.chapter_id == permit) }}, function(err, bloodrequests) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    Bloodrequest.findOne({ patient_name: req.decoded.patient_name }, function(err, mainUser) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        res.json({ success: true, bloodrequests: bloodrequests });
                    });
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: define in a common scope. But this is anti-pattern

Comment: Add `return` statement in `if (!mainUser) {...` block.

Comment: What part should I change?, Please help me to solve this

Comment: `return res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' }); `

Comment: still mainUser is not defined
:

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside the local scope.

```
 `router.get('/bloodapprovedrequestmanagement', function(req, res) {
           var permit;
            User.find({}, function(err, users) {
                if (err) throw err; 
                User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }, function(err, mainUser) {
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    if (!mainUser) {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' }); 
                    } 
                    if(mainUser.branch_id === '111') {
                        permit = mainUser.branch_id;
                        Bloodrequest.find({$where: function(err) {
                            return (this.request_status == "approved" && this.chapter_id == permit) }}, function(err, bloodrequests) {
                            if (err) throw err; 
                            Bloodrequest.findOne({ patient_name: req.decoded.patient_name }, function(err, mainUser) {
                                if (err) throw err; 
                                res.json({ success: true, bloodrequests: bloodrequests });                     
                            });
                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        });`
```

Comment: gives me:MongoError: ReferenceError: permit is not defined :
@:2:29

Comment: i have updated my answer.Lets try that.Declare the permit as global scope.

Comment: still ReferenceError: permit is not defined :( I dont know whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `callback` to `async await` that more simple.

```
router.get('/bloodapprovedrequestmanagement', function async(req, res) {
   try {
    var permit;
    let mainUser = await User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username }); 
    if(mainUser && mainUser.branch_id && mainUser.branch_id === '111') {
     permit = mainUser.branch_id;
     // here you add your condiion for (this.request_status == "approved" && this.chapter_id == permit).
     let bloodRequestData = await  Bloodrequest.findOne({ patient_name: req.decoded.patient_name });
     res.json({ success: true, bloodrequests: bloodRequestData }); 
    } 
   } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

> As per my understanding you have not used `User.find({})` and `Bloodrequest.find({})` data in your code.

Comment: gives me let mainUser = await User.findOne({ username: req.decoded.username });
                                  ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Make sure you added `async` like `function async(req, res)`